# get the index of an element within its class

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to get the index of `tr` in its class "foo",but i want it to count only the elements with this class **inside the table** and not every "foo" in the body.
So i want i to get this :

| TABLE | TABLE | TABLE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |

Instead of this :

| TABLE | TABLE | TABLE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | 6 |
| 1 | 4 | 7 |
| 2 | 5 | 8 |

I have tried the following but i get the index of `tr` in "foo" counting the whole page and not only inside the table :

```js
document.querySelectorAll("td").forEach(i => {
  $(i).text($(i).closest("tr").index(".foo"))
})
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
}

th,
td {
  border: thin solid lightgrey;
  height: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>TABLE</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="foo">
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="foo">
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="foo">
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>TABLE</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="foo">
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="foo">
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="foo">
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>TABLE</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="foo">
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="foo">
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="foo">
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you try '''parent()''' for td instead of '''closest''' ?

Comment: @SalmanA 
Because i'm trying to count only the foos within each table separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `.index()` on a collection of all the `.foo` within the current table, passing the current row as the argument. This returns its index within that collection.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("td").forEach(i => {
  let row = $(i).closest("tr");
  $(i).text(row.closest("table").find(".foo").index(row));
})
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
}

th,
td {
  border: thin solid lightgrey;
  height: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>TABLE</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="foo">
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="foo">
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="foo">
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>TABLE</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="foo">
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="foo">
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="foo">
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>TABLE</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="foo">
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="foo">
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="foo">
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `.foo` are the `tr`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using jquery .. I have commented on the code and it should be more than understandable! :)

```js
$(function(){
    $('table').each(function(){ // find all table
        if($(this).find('.foo').length > 0){  // check if the foo class is present 
            var counter = 0;
            $(this).find('.foo td').each(function(){ // Count and number cells 
                $(this).text(counter);
                counter++;
            })
        }
    })
})
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
}

th,
td {
  border: thin solid lightgrey;
  height: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>TABLE</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="foo">
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="foo">
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="foo">
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>TABLE</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="foo">
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="foo">
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="foo">
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>TABLE</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="foo">
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="foo">
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="foo">
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```